# Alfresco: Query workflow tasks for a list of users

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

I would like to be able to query workflow tasks assigned to a list of users using Activiti. For instance, query tasks assigned to user1 or user2.
I have read the code of WorkflowServiceImpl.java and ActivitiWorkflowEnginge.java, actually WorkflowTaskQuery is able to query tasks assigned to only 1 user.
I can't find how to create a new method that adds the feature I need: I did not understand how the query is converted and what exactly I can modify.
I thought if it is possible to use luceneSearch for such query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If for list of users you mean a group you could use the method with signature

`List<WorkflowTask> getPooledTasks(String authority)` in this way:

```
getWorkflowService().getPooledTasks(groupName);
```

In general you can use a method like:

```
List<WorkflowTask> queryTasks(WorkflowTaskQuery query,
                              boolean sameSession)
```

and then something like:

```
WorkflowTaskQuery query = new WorkflowTaskQuery();
query.setActive(true);
query.setTaskState(WorkflowTaskState.IN_PROGRESS);
query.setActorId("username");
List<WorkflowTask> results = workflowService.queryTasks(query, false);
```

where username represent the user you're looking for.
You can easily iterate over your user list to achieve what you need, but if this list is quite long you may encounter performance issues.

You can consider creating a temporary repository group, then add it all the user of your list and finally perform a pooled query against this group.

Remember that the `WorkflowTaskQuery` object is nothing but a filter you can compose for the `queryTasks` method.

Comment: I need to query for users that are not necessary under the same group

Comment: iteration over a user list is not a good solution. In fact, 1 query for list users, take less execution time than iteration over users.